# unable to parse JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, parsing

In JS, I am trying to go from `[{ "date": 1420174800,"value": 3},{"date": 1420261200,"value": 3 },` ***to here-->***  `{ 1352437200: 121, 1352523600: 52 };`

I am returning a [2d] JSON object and transforming as per documentation.

Data from call: after the **AJAX call returns** with data, in my jsonObj/datas,

```
[
    {
        "date": 1420174800,
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "date": 1420261200,
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "date": 1420347600,
        "value": 13
    }
]
```

---

**JS Parse** Function from the site
   *// at localdomain returns JSON shown above (both RAW and Stringified)*

```
var datas = getmyJson('/GetServices/JsonDataSvc');
var parser = function (datas) {
            var stats = {};
            for (var d in datas) {
                stats[datas[d].date] = datas[d].value;
            }
            //console.log("Data after parse", stats);
            return stats;
        };
```

Init function

```
 var cal = new CalHeatMap();
        cal.init({
            itemSelector: "#cal-heatmap",
            domain: "year",
            subDomain: "month",      
            data: datas,
            afterLoadData: parser,
            start: new Date(2015, 1, 1),
            cellSize: 15,           
            },
            legend: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            legendColors: ["#ecf5e2", "#232181"]
        });
```

The map render empty/no data:

- Is there an error, what is the expected data format/type?

Comment: When you put `stats` on the right-hand side of a `+` operator and  a string on the other side, JavaScript thinks you want the object reference converted to a string. Try `console.log("After parse: ", stats);` instead.

Comment: @Pointy never knew, thanks! *coming from .NET* :)

Comment: @Pointy  BTW, if I dont put stringify and use the comma, I only get `[object object],[object object]` ..is this what JSON looks like to the browser on return type of Json in AJAX call?

Comment: Not exactly, that's what happens when you call toString on any object in Javascript that doesn't have a toString implementation.

Comment: I think the problem is here. Can you post the code for `getmyJson()` functrion?

Comment: @adityaParab I found out the issues, the first was the time format was not understood.

Comment: @gabriel thanks for letting me know, that helped me hone in on the problem that it was the time variable. I tried to upvote, but it wont let me!